# Visual Studio 2017 not recognizing fields, nor methods of base class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Since installing the SQLite nuget package on one of my projects, Visual Studio is not working properly.

[image: Screenshot of said error]

I've tried restarting Visual Studio, reloading the solution, loading another project, and even restarting my PC, to no avail.

Comment: The place where you are writing `_Container` is not the right place. The member variable `_Container` can only be used inside a method body.

Comment: I do have an update available, and I don't mind showing my full name (Doesn't it show on my SO profile?). Anyway, after trying to call the container inside a method, the base class method I mentioned also was suggested: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU0KO.png)